# Datatables Uncaught Type Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have Datatables together with GridRowCount() to get row counts by specified groups in a html table, the jfiddle site is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/RgKPZ/). When I run the code the chrome browser throws up an uncaught type error (...).live is not a function.

The error from the console is displayed.

```html
rowtoggle.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a function
rowtoggle.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a functionGridRowCount @ rowtoggle.js:30(anonymous function) @ rowtoggle.js:16i @ jquery-1.12.2.min.js:2j.fireWith @ jquery-1.12.2.min.js:2n.extend.ready @ jquery-1.12.2.min.js:2K @ jquery-1.12.2.min.js:2
Navigated to http://localhost/datacentre/admin/request_pending.php
rowtoggle.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a functionGridRowCount @ rowtoggle.js:30(anonymous function) @ rowtoggle.js:16i @ jquery-1.12.2.min.js:2j.fireWith @ jquery-1.12.2.min.js:2n.extend.ready @ jquery-1.12.2.min.js:2K @ jquery-1.12.2.min.js:2
Navigated to http://localhost/datacentre/admin/request_pending.php
```

Below is the code of the Datatables and the GroupRowCount() pluggin.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#example').dataTable({
    
       "bLengthChange": false,
              "bPaginate": false,
              "bJQueryUI": true     
   }).rowGrouping({
        iGroupingColumnIndex: 1,
        sGroupingColumnSortDirection: "asc",
        iGroupingOrderByColumnIndex: 0 ,  
  bExpandableGrouping: true,
        bExpandSingleGroup: false,
        iExpandGroupOffset: -1,
        asExpandedGroups: [""]
    });
 GridRowCount();
});

function GridRowCount() {
            $('span.rowCount-grid').remove();
            $('input.expandedOrCollapsedGroup').remove();

            $('.dataTables_wrapper').find('[id|=group-id]').each(function () {
                var rowCount = $(this).nextUntil('[id|=group-id]').length;
                $(this).find('td').append($('<span />', { 'class': 'rowCount-grid' }).append($('<b />', { 'text': rowCount })));
            });

            $('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.dataTables_filter').append($('<input />', { 'type': 'button', 'class': 'expandedOrCollapsedGroup collapsed', 'value': 'Expanded All Group' }));

            **$('.expandedOrCollapsedGroup').live('click', function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {**
                    $(this).addClass('expanded').removeClass('collapsed').val('Collapse All Group').parents('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.collapsed-group').trigger('click');
                }
                else {
                    $(this).addClass('collapsed').removeClass('expanded').val('Expanded All Group').parents('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.expanded-group').trigger('click');
                }
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.live()` has been deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in version 1.9. You should use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('.expandedOrCollapsedGroup').on('click', function () {
//Your code
})
```